# Two lists comparison with replacing elements Python

Tags: python, list, comparison

I have some configuration file named `file1` with row:

`if [data] in [ "data01", "data02", "data03" ] {`

and another file named `file2` with rows:

```
dATa02
datA03

dAta04
```

From `file1` I'm using regular expression for pasring data from row: `if [data] in [ "data01", "data02", "data03" ] {`

```
import re
with open('/file1', 'r') as f:
    for l in f:
        l_s = row.strip()
        if 'if [data] in ' in row_s:
            data1 = re.findall('"(.\w+)\"*', l_s)
            print(data1)
```

As a result I get a list `data1`:
`[ 'data01', 'data02", 'data03' ]`

From `file2` I'm parsing data with skipping empty rows and making an elements lowercase:

```
with open('/file2', 'r') as f:
    data2 = [l.lower() for l in (line.strip() for line in f) if l]
    print(data2)
```

As a result I get a anouther list `data2`:
`[ 'data02', 'data03", 'data04' ]`

I need to compare two lists `data1` and `data2` with adding new elements and deleting non-existing from `data2` in `data1`. As a result, I what to know which elements were added/deleted.

Comment: so you need an `intersection` of the two lists essentially?

Comment: no, the actual data list should be ```data2```. In other words, replacing ```data1``` with ```data2``` will achieve my needs, but I want to use comparison to know with elements were deleted/added from ```data2``` in ```data1```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into `sets` in python.

```
added = set(data2) - set(data1) #data04
deleted = set(data1) - set(data2) #data01
```

Comment: Sets are the correct solution here and also have other nice properties. For example, O(1) membership checks.